# How do I make this responsive?

Tags: css, express, responsive-design, ejs, responsive

OKAY. So, I am creating a Chat site/application and I know next to nothing about CSS.
But I am alone in developing this thing, so I gotta try.
I designed the site in Photoshop, then I moved on to actually creating it w/ HTML & CSS and it looks great, but not all parts are responsive.
More specifically the messages container thing, can someone help me with either learning how to do responsiveness or just spoonfeed the entire site but with responsiveness for me?

Here's my code so far:
HTML (combined with EJS):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home - <%= name %></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/global.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="nav">
                <h1 class="navTitle">Atlas Chat</h1>
                <h2 class="navUsername"><%= user ? user.username : "Not logged in" %></h2>
                <% if(user !== null) { %>
                <a class="navitem logoutbtn" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                <% } else { %>
                <a class="navitem loginbtn" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="navitem" href="/register">Register</a>
                <% } %>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="roomInfo">
                    <span class="hashtag">#</span><input type="text" class="roomname" pattern="^[a-z0-9\-]{0,16}$" required placeholder="channel-name"><button class="roomnamebtn">Join</button>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="room">
                    <ul class="messages">
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is a message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                        <li class="message"><span class="user">Atlas</span>: <span class="msgContent">This is another message.</span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="inputarea">
                        <hr class="inputhr">
                        <input type="text" class="roominput" placeholder="<%= user ? "Send a message." : "Log in to join the conversation!" %>" <%= user ? "" : "disabled" %> required><button class="roomsendbtn" <%= user ? "" : "disabled" %>>Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="users">
                <h1 class="usersTitle">Online Users</h1>
                <ul class="usersList">
                    <li class="usersUser">Atlas</li>
                    <li class="usersUser">SomeOtherGuy</li>
                    <li class="usersUser">SomeThirdGuy</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root {
    --bg1: #131318;
    --bg2: #1E1E26;
    --link1: #2991E9;
    --link2: #1B83DA;
    --btn1: #9638E5;
    --btn2: #8933D1;
    --text1: #ffffff;
    --text2: #626262;
    --border: #252525;
    --success: #28D328;
    --danger: #EA2828;
}

:focus {
    outline: initial;
}

html {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: var(--bg1);
    color: white;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-weight: 500;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #35A7FF;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2887D7;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: var(--btn1);
    text-align: center;
}

.navitem {
    background-color: var(--btn1);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navitem:hover {
    background-color: var(--btn2);
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.users {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--btn1);
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}

.logoutbtn, .loginbtn {
    margin-top: auto;
}

.navTitle, .usersTitle {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.roomInfo {
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.hashtag {
    font-size: 3rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 16px;
    color: var(--text2);
}

input.roomname {
    width: 14%;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: var(--text2);
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    background-color: var(--bg2);
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

input.roomname:focus {
    border: 1px solid var(--btn2);
}

input.roominput {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: var(--text1);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-color: var(--bg2);
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

input.roominput:focus {
    border: 1px solid var(--btn2);
}

input.roominput:disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 15px;
    margin-inline-end: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--bg2);
}

ul.messages {
    max-height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

li.message {
    max-height: 20px;
}

li.message:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

button.roomnamebtn {
    width: 7%;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background-color: var(--btn1);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.roomsendbtn {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background-color: var(--btn1);
    color: white;
    margin-top: 14px;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.roomsendbtn:disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: var(--btn2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive design means it changes to the size and shape of the screen.
For example, mobile designs and layouts would look silly on desktop, while desktop designs would be too cluttered to fit on mobile.

A while back I was making a mockup of a chatapp, if you don't mind I would like to use that as an example since I have the code already online to look at.

https://replit.com/@DillonBurnett/VapidDeficientTitles#index.html

When you are on mobile, the app would look something like this:

[image]

Here it is nice and easy to view, you have the chat and you can tap the buttons at the top right to view rooms, users, and settings... but this looks a little simple when viewing it on a desktop, so instead I use a bit of css to change it specifically when the screen is large to look like this:

[image]

Each "screen" is in a long div. Think of it like 4 screens width at 100% each, but they are simply hidden because they go offscreen. When you select a different "screen" it simply scrolls there instantly making it look like a new page.

```
#screens{
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#screens #viewport{
    width: calc(100% * 4); height: 100%;
    overflow: none;
}
#screens #viewport > *{
    width: calc(100% / 4); height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

However, when the user is on desktop and I want to show the "rooms" and the "chat" at the same time, I simply adjust those to fit within 1 screen.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
    #screens #viewport #rooms{width: 200px!important}
    #screens #viewport #chat{width: calc(100% / 4 - 200px)!important;}
}
```

As you can see the **@media** tag is unique and only allows the css within it to run when the screen is at least 800 wide. Otherwise, it is simply ignored. This opens up a lot of potential for css. You can adjust your layout for portrait or landscape, widths, heights to target many different devices... even Tvs.

I used that example because the css is generally simple and easy to understand... While it is a bit long (css declarations), I hope it helps you in designing a responsive chat app. If you have any specific questions about the example let me know below.